# Invalid route name, already in use: 'root' (M. Hartl Tutorial)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, console

I am running into a problem I can't solve for several days. I've been searching StackOverflow for the same problem and definitely there are other such issues, but being too new into Rails most of the things I find are a bit too advanced for my level and I am not sure if they apply to me.

So, the problem is this.

I follow a tutorial (Hartl's) and at some point I have to deploy on Heroku, which goes alright, but then when I run

```
heroku run console --sandbox
```

I get the error

```
Invalid route name, already in use: 'root'
```

This is the message from the console:

```
Invalid route name, already in use: 'root'  (ArgumentError)
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option,
or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the
same naming.
```

I also get a few warnings when deploying to Heroku, which I am not sure if are related to this issue:

```
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
remote:        Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled
properly.
remote:        This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your
app.
remote:        In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your
dependencies at all.

remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
remote:        To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
remote:        ruby '2.0.0'

remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
remote:        Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled 
properly.
remote:        This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your
app.
remote:        In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your 
dependencies at all.

remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        No Procfile detected, using the default web server (webrick)
```

I am also getting the same error when I try to start the server in the production environment:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

and then

```
rails server --environment production
```

Both the test and development environments start fine, but not the production. With what little knowledge I still have, I'm guessing it has to do with that, but again, I feel like I'm going in circles already.

Here's my routes.rb file (it's pretty simple, so I fail to see the problem in it):

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root                 'static_pages#home'
  get 'help'       =>  'static_pages#help'
  get 'about'      =>  'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact'    =>  'static_pages#contact'
  get 'users/new'  =>  'users#new'
  resources :users

end
```

None of this prevents me from continuing with the tutorial since all else works fine, but this just bugs me too much and I just need to figure out what the problem is! Could it be some bug, something else? I really don't know any more. It may be something totally simple, but I am already too tired of looking for the problem.

Anyway, if you need the source of any other file I have, I will post it. FYI, I am at the end of chapter 6 right before the exercises. I must point out that this is when I discovered the issue, upon trying the 'heroku run console' command. This problem may have been present before but I never ran into it.

EDIT: If you could point me to some direction, somewhere I haven't looked or considered, like some idea what it may be... It will much appreciated!

EDIT: I forgot to include that I am working in cloud9 IDE, if that matters at all.

The output of the 'rake routes' command:

```
 root      GET  /                    'static_pages#home'
 help      GET  /help(.:format)      'static_pages#help'
 contact   GET  /contact(.:format)   'static_pages#contact'
 about     GET  /about(.:format)     'static_pages#about'
 users_new GET  /users/new(.:format) 'users#new'
```

Comment: If something is working in development, but not production, the first thing I would do is double (triple) check that I have committed everything in development to my repository and have pulled the latest code when deploying to production.  Hartl explains these steps in detail.  Perhaps (at one point) you had an error in your routes and have corrected it, but have not committed the change.

Comment: Actually after following several other tutorials I got used to committing my code to my git repository almost all the time. So, currently everything is freshly committed. After that, I commit to heroku (that I do much rarely though). But again, right now everything is committed to git and heroku. I think something is wrong with my routes. I'm running into another issue with my '/users', but I don't know if this one is related to my original post.

Comment: The only place I took a slight swerve from Hartl's tutorial is to replace his 'signup' (in the routes.rb) with 'users/new'. For some reason the 'signup' URI pattern didn't work for me (and even if I change it now it fails the entire application). I then changed the path to be 'users_new_path'. All of this worked for me, but now I can't access the '/users/1' (I have created a user with id:1). So, since this is the only thing different from Hartl's tutorial, I'm suspecting it has to do with this. @steve klein, do you think this may have been the problem?

Comment: Yes that could definitely be a problem Evelyn, although it wouldn't explain why something that is working in development is not working in production.  A couple notes - I found it very valuable to go through Hartl's tutorial exactly as is, finding and fixing issues (typos etc) as I went.  As a result, I have the complete tutorial built and can (and do) refer to it as needed.  Secondly, your `users_new` route looks quite funky.  Note that the next line (`resources :users`) will give you 7 Restful routes for users, including a route for a new user.

Comment: If you are not seeing those seven routes when you run `rake routes`, something is seriously wrong.  I would remove that route you added.

Comment: Yes, `rake routes` doesn't show me those additional routes after adding the `resources :users` line. In fact, with or without it, nothing changes when I print the routes. I'm considering starting the tutorial from scratch and figuring out what I did wrong. But again, the only single thing I changed was I changed the `get 'signup' => 'users#new'` to be `get 'users/new' => 'users#new'`. For some reason Hartl's version with 'signup' just didn't work, and I've been following him strictly. Anyway, I'll start over, that's a good exercise and see what I messed up.